# How do I disable an MVC controller by code?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using [SelfHost/Katana/Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.SelfHost/) for my WebServer. 
I have a Controller in there that I want to enable/disable by code depending on a command line argument at launch time.

Is there a simple way of doing this in MVC?

Right now I'm thinking in the Controller's code to return HTTP-NotFound status code when this config is disabled, any better ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could decorate your controller with a custom `Action Filter`.

```
public class ConfigActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {   
  // This method is called before a controller action is executed.
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    if(someConfigSetting) {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Error", someRouteValues);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Usage:

```
[ConfigActionFilter]
public class MyController : Controller {
  ...
}
```

More [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a redirecttoaction that will take users to a different controller explaining what's happening.

ie:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private IConfigReader _configReader;

    public MyController(IConfigReader configReader){ //not sure if you're doing dependency injection or not, so I'm injecting it
         _configReader = configReader;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        if(!_configReader.IsEnabled) {
            return RedirectToAction("Denied", "AuthController");
        }

        //etc

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an attribute, apply it to the controller and set a static property on that attribute at startup time, and deny access (or return "Not found") when the flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can implement a custom AuthorizationAttribute and put it on your controller

```
public class AuthorizationAdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (/*check for argument*/)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
            {
                // ** IMPORTANT **
                // Since we're performing authorization at the action level, the authorization code runs
                // after the output caching module. In the worst case this could allow an authorized user
                // to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later be served the
                // cached page. We work around this by telling proxies not to cache the sensitive page,
                // then we hook our custom authorization code into the caching mechanism so that we have
                // the final say on whether a page should be served from the cache.

                HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
                cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
                cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);
            }
            else
            {                  
                filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
            }
        }

        private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
        {
            validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        }
    }
```